# Implement Authorize.net ARB from a CIM record

Tags: e-commerce, authorize.net, authorize.net-cim, authorize.net-arb

I'm implementing a payment system with real-time payment and also with recurring payment.

For instant payment I'm using `CIM` and its working fine with customer profile, payment profile and shipping info etc.

Now I'm trying to create a recurring billing schedule from that CIM records instead of using the `ARB api` again.

Is that possible to implement a `ARB` schedule using `CIM` records created through **programming** instead of manual way from merchant account.

Please help me with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to create a subscription ARB from a CIM profile through the API (if at all).

Comment: Sir, thanks for the answer. after reading the docs I get that.